# Go_Router triggers redirect everytime i use push and go (internal routing) and I only want to trigger redirect on authStateChanges

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am building the authentication setup and I want to redirect users upon authStateChanges. To do that I use the redirect property of the Go_Router package which works just fine. However, navigating routes with push and go also trigger the redirect property which messes up my routes since I only want to redirect upon authStateChanges not internal routing processes like push and go. And I have searched everywhere and I can’t find the answer to solve this anywhere, how can I tell redirect to ignore when I navigate between routes?

Understand go_router redirect property and how can I control and ignore when using internal routing

Comment: Did you find any solution?